# docker run hello-world - unable to find image

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I installed latest docker version on remote Centos7.2 (version 18.01.0.ce) according the docker install instruction.
My docker client and docker server are on the same machine (Virtual machine). 
when running `sudo docker run hello-world` I get

> "Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
>   docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: >net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout >exceeded while awaiting headers).
>   See 'docker run --help'."

Any suggestions on how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

The first time you run `docker container run hello-world` the system will not be able to find the image(container) locally so it should automatically attempt to download the container - it did in my case.

Also looks like a connection issue with docker.io you might want to try later or check your internet connection settings.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have internet access on that virtual machine.

When you run non-existing docker image, docker engine connects to docker hub and download that image.

Answer (score 0):

I have also met this issue when I try to run [centos 7](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos?tab=tags&page=1&name=7) docker from docker hub:

```
docker run -it centos:7
```

The first message issued was:

> Unable to find image 'centos:7' locally

After a while, I saw the following message:

> 7: Pulling from library/centos
>   Digest: sha256:307835c385f656ec2e2fec602cf093224173c51119bbebd602c53c3653a3d6eb
>   Status: Downloaded newer image for centos:7

Then I am able to go inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up proxies and DNS settings were of no use in my case.

After extensive research for a couple of days, I was able to overcome the issue using below steps in docker-toolbox bash:

1. Stop the host docker virtual machine:

`$ docker-machine stop default`

2. Delete the host:

`$ docker-machine rm default`

3. Create new VirtualBox machine named ***default***:

`$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

4. Verify if the machine is runnning. **ACTIVE** attribute should be marked *:
   `$ docker-machine ls`
5. If the machine is not running, run the machine:
   `$ docker-machine run default`

Then, run hello-world, you will get below screen in your bash

[image: docker-toolbox CLI]

Hope it help you guys and save your time!